# What is the function of T in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I came accross this SQL script, it works like it is mean to, but I I have been trying to figure oiut the function of **T** in the script.

```
 sprintf("SELECT username 
FROM (SELECT * FROM users
      WHERE spillover_sponsor=%s 
      ORDER BY unique_id DESC 
      LIMIT 3) t
ORDER BY unique_id ASC LIMIT 1", GetSQLValueString($_POST['mysponsor'], "text"));
```

Comment: T is an (unused) alias for the inner query

Comment: flagged to be moved on dba.stackexchange

Comment: Can you provide more context, like a link to an article or so. I will appreciate that a lot.

Comment: @DDS I don't think that's a good idea, the question is about a feature of the SQL language (and a trivial one at that) so the question is probably as inappropiate over there than it is here.

Comment: @DDS please stop unnecessarily flagging questions

Comment: "flagged to be moved on dba.stackexchange" @DDS ? Why it is not a pure MySQL question because the code also contains PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T is an alias for the inner query

```
(SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE spillover_sponsor=%s 
  ORDER BY unique_id DESC 
  LIMIT 3) t
```

Aliases can be used to create a temporary name for columns or tables as:-

```
column_name [ AS ] alias_column_name
table_name [ AS ] alias_table_name
```

AS is an optional parameter, can be used or omitted as per coding style preferences.

Answer (score 2):

`t` is here an alias for the resulting table of this part of your SQL query:

> ```
>   SELECT * FROM users
>   WHERE spillover_sponsor=%s 
>   ORDER BY unique_id DESC 
>   LIMIT 3
> ```

For more information, here's a post on how to use subqueries in the `SELECT` statement:
https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-20-using-subqueries-in-the-select-statement/

Answer (score 1):

It is an alias for the temporary result of the sub-query between the parentheses.
You could use `AS t` to be more explicit, or you could give it a more meaningful name.

```
SELECT username
FROM (SELECT * FROM users 
      WHERE spillover_sponsor=%s
      ORDER BY unique_id DESC LIMIT 3)
AS SponseredByMySponsor 
ORDER BY unique_id ASC LIMIT 1
```

SQL requires you to give it a name when using sub-queries like that.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have covered what `t` is.  More importantly, it is not needed.  You can write the query using `offset` and not use a subquery:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.spillover_sponsor = %s 
ORDER BY u.unique_id DESC 
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2;
```

Oh, look!  I used `u` as a table alias for `users`.  This is exactly the same idea as `t`.